# .htaccess special rule exception for ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

So having very little experience with Regex as well as minor beef with .htaccess I need to ask this:

I want to use AJAX on my site, but my mod rewrite configuration prevents me from doing this properly, as I redirected all urls to my `index.php` and set the **url** `$_GET` variable, this is my current setup:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now I want this rule to not fire if the query contains "`&ajax&`" as a string, at least I always append "`&ajax&time=...`" to the ajax path that I want to load.

So I thought it would be easiest to check if I can match "ajax" and use the `[S]`kip or `[L]`ast Flag to prevent the other rule to fire, but haven't been able to achieve it yet, any help? With explanations or pointers toward some?

Also, it would be neat if this doesn't require absolute urls or anything, as I want it to work in both development (localhost) and live (actual domain) environment without changing the .htaccess file accordingly.

**SO**

- I want the url `example.com/profile`
- to be redirected to `example.com/index.php?url=profile`

**AND**

- I want the url `example.com/src/file.php?stuff=something&ajax&time=1234`
- to stay `example.com/src/file.php?stuff=something&ajax&time=1234`

**BUT**

- I want the url `example.com/ajax`
- to also be redirected to `example.com/index.php?url=ajax` (just in case)

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add another `RewriteCond` in your rule that skips this rule if query string contains `ajax`:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)ajax [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The htaccess file shouldn't rewrite requests for valid files. This is the line that says so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

So what you want should already be  happening, assuming src/file.php exists on the server.

Comment: Yeah just checked, might be just my ajax path not being correct. thanks for the tip, can you tell me how I would go about it though? for future reference?
So assuming I want to skip a certain rule when a string is found in the query?

Comment: So I looked into it, and my path that I used in AJAX was fine, the problem I have is that the current setup with my rules, the file can only be opened properly if there is no query string after it. But as soon as there's $_GET parameters attached, its redirected to index.php

Comment: You can use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} regex_here` to run a regex against the query string portion of a URL.

Comment: I'm not sure how the query string would impact the .htaccess file you shared here. Apache should still "see" the file, fail the not-a-file `RewriteCond`, and use the file for the request. You may want to download xampp / start in a clean environment, add the .htaccess file and the `src/file.php` script, and see if you see the same or different behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the help jstur, I can't flag comments as accepted answer, but anubhava posted the same you suggested, just as a full example, so I accepted his. Thanks again though!